# C# Api image to picturebox from url. Exception thrown

Tags: c#, image, exception, memory, picturebox

I am trying to create a little application and display images of cats from thecatapi.com. I call CATS() on a timer every 10 seconds. The code runs fine for 3-5 images then i get "System.ArgumentException: 'parameter is not valid.'" Ive tried to use try/catch but it still throws an exception. Pointers as to a solution are much appreciated.

```cs
string catURL;
string catJSON;

private async void CATS()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?api_key=<apiKey>");

    HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

    using(var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
    {
        catJSON = (await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
    }
    dynamic items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(catJSON);
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        catURL = Convert.ToString(item.url);
    }
    try
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Load(catURL);
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: `catch { }` is pretty useless. Add some code there to print out the error.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but how would i do that?

Comment: @TobyHogg easiest would be if you look up the microsoft docs for try-catch.

Comment: Something like: `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);}` See also: [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/)

Comment: Needn't be the problem, but it is recommended not to dispose of a pbox.Image directly. Instead do the little dance: `Image dummy = pictureBox1.Image; pictureBox1.Image = null; if (dummy != null) dummy.Dispose();`

Comment: Catch is not actually happening. The exception is thrown within the try so I get no output

Comment: That means the error is before the `try`. Put the entire function inside the `try`.

Comment: Did you try my advice?

Comment: The error is Inside the try, I can move the try to the entire function and it still throws an exception. It is weird that it bypasses the try/catch though.

Comment: @TaW your advice did work thank you.